# How to fix 'JSON Parse Error: unexpected identifier array' when making an AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm setting up a Contact Form Validation and i need the variable $msg from a php script 'sendEmail.php'. The actual mailing system is working, the script is receiving the form input's from index.php and is working(Successfully sending emails)...
The thing is the 'success: function(data)' isn't working, and have been couple days trying to figure out what i'm doing wrong

I've tried to change to $.post function, compared a lot of examples similar, debugging with the 'error:' function...

The error displays on the console 'console.log(errorThrown)'

I'm using Safari and i get this from the XHRs folder from the sendEmail.php:
Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(12) "asfasfasfasf"
  ["email"]=>
  string(9) "asfasfasf"
  ["message"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
{"code":404,"msg":"Please fill in all fields"}
```

```
// AJAX Call
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "php/sendEmail.php",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    name: name,
    email: email,
    message: message
  },
  success: function(data) {

  if (data.code == '200') {
    $('.alert-success').html(data.msg);
    $('.alert-success').css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    $('.alert-danger').html(data.msg);
    $('.alert-danger').css('display', 'block');
  }

  },error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

```php
// Error Message
$msg = '';

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {

    // Get Form Data
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

    var_dump($_POST);

    // Verifications
    if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($message)) {
        // Name Check
        if (strlen($name) <= 4 || strlen($name) >= 30) {
            $msg = 'Please type a name between 4 and 30 characters';
        } else {
            // Email Check
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $msg = 'Please provide a valid email';
            } else {
                // Message Check
                if (strlen($message) < 10) {
                    $msg = 'Please provide a message superior to 10           characters';
                } else {
                    // Send Email
                        $msg = 'Email was sent successfully...';
                        echo json_encode(['code' => 200, 'msg' => $msg]);
                        exit;
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $msg = 'Error: Email was not sent...';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Please fill in all fields';
    }
}

echo json_encode(['code' => 404, 'msg' => $msg]);

``
```

Comment: as in `echo json_encode(['code' => 404, 'msg' => $msg]);`

Comment: I'm sorry forgot the echo, but the problem stays the same!

Comment: Make sure you don't have _any_ output before or after you echo the data (that includes spaces, line breaks etc). A good practice is also to have an `exit;` after you echo the json-data to prevent anything else being executed. Also, check the network tab in the browsers dev-tools when you make a request so you can see what it actually returns. It could be some error message further up in the file.

Comment: Please copy/paste your _actual_ code instead of re-writing something similar by hand.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is in your code (client) and not thrown by the server?

Comment: It looks like you're having a `var_dump()` in your code before your output. That would do it. Remove it and try again. As mentioned, you can't have _any_ output before or after the echo json_encode(...) or the response won't be valid json.

Comment: You're doing a `var_dump()` somewhere.  Remove that.

Comment: You guy's are awesome thank you! Solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking you code and this:

```
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(12) "asfasfasfasf"
  ["email"]=>
  string(9) "asfasfasf"
  ["message"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
{"code":404,"msg":"Please fill in all fields"}
```

I realize that you have a var_dump in your code at this point:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {

    // Get Form Data
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

    var_dump($_POST); // <---- Remove this and everything should be okay
```

Hope it hepls